# Firefox bookmarks toolbar like Chrome

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, toolbar

Can I get my Firefox bookmarks *toolbar* to automatically display the top-level bookmark folders from my bookmarks *menu*, instead of having to manage copies of bookmarks in the menu & toolbar?

I noticed that Chrome does this so I'm wondering if there's a way to do it for Firefox.

Or how can we submit an "addon request"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the Bookmarks sidebar (Ctrl+B) or Organize Bookmarks(Ctrl+Shift+O) and drag Bookmarks Menu or Recently Bookmarked to the Bookmarks Toolbar.

Comment: Will it sync when I add items to those folders in the menu?

Comment: Recently Bookmarked syncs as soon as you add a new bookmark, it is displayed on top of the list. 
Look at the Organize Bookmarks panel, you will find variety of ways to organize them.